# Filling holes for an extrusion

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine

I created an extrusion via a font art svg and tried to create a mesh from the model so that I could select the closed loop edges, ideally from one face to the other, and fill those holes as shown below. The Mesh-->Cleanup-->Fill Holes method did not work for me. I then tried to extrude from one closed edge loop to the backside but did not know how to point at the two reference planes (front and back). I am new to Blender, so there were probably steps I missed from the documentation/tutorial. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: first remove the faces inside of the hole, and then merge by distance those boundary vertices, and then create a face in that boundary, and press ctrl+x to disolve these vertices...

Comment: before extruding, you can simplify the topology with a X > Limited Dissolve, then delete these holes manually?